# why postgresql-9.4 has no installation candidate

Tags: postgresql

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql-9.4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-9.4' has no installation candidate
```

I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

postgresql-9.4 has been updated to postgresql-9.5 in the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-9.5
```

postgresql-9.x has been updated to postgresql-9.6 in the default Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10 repositories. postgresql-9.x has been updated to postgresql-10 in the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 only ships PostgreSQL 9.5 (`postgresql-9.5`). PostgreSQL 9.4 is not available in any supported version of Ubuntu

If you don't need a special version of PostgreSQL you can just install the package `postgresql` to install whatever version your Ubuntu ships. In  this case a distro upgrade will automatically upgrade PostgreSQL if needed.

Comment: This is a duplicate of my previously posted answer. Do you want to fade out or shall I contribute? –

Comment: @karel .. you answered 13:00:52 and Florian 13:01:03 - that's within 11 seconds, so probably both answers has been written in parallel.

Comment: That is also the opinion of some moderators. The opinion of some moderators in case you're interested is that several duplicate answers to the same question can be posted if they are posted within a few minutes of each other. However the privilege of posting multiple duplicate answers without them being possibly closed as duplicate answers fades out over time.